# Set GridView in center horizontal

Tags: android, gridview

I have an application in which I am using a GridView to show some image of different number. I want to set the GridView in the center of screen horizontally that is to be run perfect on every phone of different sizes or density pixels. 
Thanks in advance.
code

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: set gridview  android:gravity="center_horizontal"  will work for relative layout.You can also set the android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" for relative_layout.Is it not working?

Comment: @AppMobiGurmeet..no it doesn't work I have tried all of them.

Answer (score 6):

your 'GridView' must be in some parent layout for example Linearlayout.Set following two properties of that parent layout

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:gravity="center"
```

Note:You must use both attributes at the same